# Perl - With overriden method avoid super() is called

Tags: perl, perl-module, moose

I'm trying to create the abstract method pattern using Perl and Moose. What I don't understand is that if I override a method from the **AbstractClass** it will eventually be called anyway. Why is this and is there a way to avoid the superclass from being called?

**Main**

```
package main;
use AbstractSort;
use OrderedSort;

# Sub class test
my $ordered = OrderedSort->new(array => [1, -1, 23, 34123, -24324]);
$ordered->sortData();
```

**AbstractClass**

```
package AbstractSort;
use namespace::autoclean; # Trims EXPORTER 
use Moose;

has 'array' => (traits  => ['Array'],
            is => 'ro', 
            isa => 'ArrayRef[Int]', 
            default => sub { [] },
            handles => {    
                get_array => 'get',
                count_array  => 'count',
            });

sub sortData{
    my $self = shift;

    print "Sorting data..\n";

    _sortAlgorithm($self->array);

    # ...
}

# Protected method here is the actual algorithm
sub _sortAlgorithm {
    die 'You must override _sortAlgorithm() in a subclass';
    # but Moose will always call the superclass which then makes it die
}
```

**SubClass**

```
package OrderedSort;
use namespace::autoclean; # Trims EXPORTER 
use Moose;
extends 'AbstractSort';

# Override and mmpl _sortAlgorithm
override _sortAlgorithm => sub {
   my $self = shift;
   # ....
};

before '_sortAlgorithm' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    # ...

    return;
};
```

Comment: Are you sure? Please show a [mcve]. If I add packages to your code it works for me. I do not see it `die`, and the `before` handler is called first.

Comment: I've edited the post with a test example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `_sortAlgorithm` as a function in the same package in AbstractSort`, and not as a method.

```
sub sortData {
    my $self = shift;

    # there is something missing here!
    _sortAlgorithm( $self->array );
}
```

That way, it will always be called in the same package, because it's not an OOP method call.

You need to do `$self->_sortAlgorithm` instead.

```
sub sortData {
    my $self = shift;

    print "Sorting data..\n";

    $self->_sortAlgorithm( $self->array );

    # ...
}
```

It will now not `die` any more, because it looks up the `_sortAlgorithm` method on `$self`, which is an instance of your subclass.

The fact that you actually have `my $self = shift` on your overridden method could have given that away, as you were also not passing `$self` into it.

---

You should also not be passing around `$self->array`. The algorithm method also has access to `$self->array`, so if you want to sort the data that is attached to your object, just use it directly in there.

Also note that typical naming conventions in Perl suggest snake_case method and variable names, and CamelCase package names.